# Inject environment variable values into config files in GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

When I previously used Azure DevOps for CI/CD, we would store secrets like database passwords in Azure DevOps environment variables, and then during the CD phase the appropriate environment's passwords would be injected into the connection strings in config files. This meant that the passwords were never stored in the repo itself.

I'm now trying to configure CI/CD in our self-hosted GitLab instance and have it working at a very basic level but I'm wondering how I go about doing the same thing as I did with Azure DevOps. I have created environments for my project and variables (masked and protected) for each environment. But is there a way to inject the values of the variables into config files during a CD deployment job?

I think for the Azure DevOps pipeline we executed a PowerShell script to replace some placeholder text in the config files with the values of the variables at deploy time. Might a similar approach work with GitLab's CD pipelines? GitLab's [documentation on where variables can be used](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html) doesn't seem to mention anything like this.

Comment: You should be able to use the same powershell script in GitLab, provided powershell is installed in the runner/image you are using. You could add that, for example, in a `before_script:` for the deploy job.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in your **project’s Settings > CI/CD and expand the Variables** section
You can also store in Group variables if your using a private instance of gitlab

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-project